# windows 8.1 machines have black screen after removing one of two domain controllers

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller, windows-8.1

We recently had a DC crash out, fortunately(?) not our GC, so we removed it from AD, and DNS.

Most of the machines on the network (All of our XP, 7 , 8 machines) appear to have picked up the new DC config, however all of our 8.1 machines have suddenly developed a black screen after logging in.

The event log seems to suggest a problem with group policies, however these have not changed. I've tried re-adding these computers to the domain (no errors)

Any ideas of how to get rid of the black screen wait time considering this appears to be only affecting 8.1 machines

Comment: What kind of stuff are you seeing in the Event Log on the Windows 8.1 machines that's different after the server changes?

Comment: What IP address do you get when you ping your local domain name?  Does it show a server that isn't there?  Do your domain controllers have errors when you run DCDiag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @arcesso Tried pinging the domain name which tried to resolved to the crashed out DC. Had another look at DNS and it appeared to have kept a record in the cache. once that was gone the machines correctly picked up the correct IP